# Returning the first result from another table if statement is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm struggling to find the logic for the next problem:

I got 2 tables

TABLE A has the following column

```
Postalcode
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

TABLE B has the following column

```
Postalcode
1111AA
1111BB
1111CA
2222AA etc
```

What I would like to have is that if the Postalcodes first 4 numbers are found from Table A in table B, then I would like to have the first result of that postalcode from Table B (4digits+2letters).

e.g. if the postalcode in A is 1111 and substring(postalcode, 1, 4) of Table B is also 1111, then return the first result of that postalcode from Table B --> 1111AA

I can't seem to find the answer for this and I'm struggling for a while now.

Hope you guys have the solution for me.

Comment: Do you mean 4 first _digits_?

Comment: No, the result should return the first value from table B --> so the first 4 digits+2 letters.  I want to use that result in my Table A.

Comment: Does Table B has an id autoincrement to determine the order, or a date_column with the inserted date of the row ?

Comment: it has an id autoincrement (sk) and an Load DateTime column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for *each record in table A* you want to match *at most one record from Table B*, an `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...)` should do the trick.

Try:

```
select a.PostalCode, b1.Postalcode
from table_a  a
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from table_b b
    where b.Postalcode LIKE a.Postalcode + '%'
    order by b.id
) b1
order by a.PostalCode;
```

If you wish to omit results that have no matching table_b record, change the `OUTER APPLY` to a `CROSS APPLY`. A `OUTER APPLY` is like a `LEFT JOIN` while a `CROSS APPLY` is like an `INNER JOIN`.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2580049face30db99c5e4c27c0a5904e) fr a demo.

(Credit Bernd Buffen for the data setup. Note that I changed PostalCode from INT to VARCHAR to simplify the match criteria.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: `MySQL`

```
select b.Postalcode
from table_a  a
inner join table_b b on LEFT(b.Postalcode,4)=a.Postalcode
where a.Postalcode=1111
order by b.id asc limit 1;
```

[Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b62e446ec6f07121ec90181640d99e08)

`SQL Server`

```
select top(1) b.Postalcode
from table_a  a
inner join table_b b on LEFT(b.Postalcode,4)=a.Postalcode
where a.Postalcode=1111
order by b.id ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d62f4f396a5302f1a47b90f33be785a)

**Edit based on comments***
I think you need something like below, but check @Bernd Buffen suggestion for performance:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
         SELECT  Postalcode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY LEFT(Postalcode,4) ORDER BY id asc ) row_num
         FROM  table_b 
            )
SELECT  cte.Postalcode 
FROM table_a a  
INNER JOIN cte  on LEFT(cte.Postalcode,4)=a.Postalcode
WHERE row_num = 1 ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3751a04ee1696b390caeb7580fd030db)

Comment: Note: this sample cant use an index. So this query generates a FULL TABLE SCAN.
It can be better to add a virtual column with index in table b that holds LEFT(b.Postalcode,4)

Comment: @Ergest Basha
Thanks for your input. I want to make the WHERE clausule more generic and I did the following:

,,,    select B.Postalcode
    INTO #Postalcode
    FROM [TABLE A]() [FCT]
    INNER JOIN TABLE B B
     ON LEFT(b.Postalcode,4) = [FCT].Postalcode
     WHERE [FCT].Postalcode = LEFT(b.BK_Postcode,4)
     ORDER BY B.ID ASC ,,,

I dont have LIMIT function in ssms. Will this work? I want to have the first value back from TABLE B if the WHERE clausule is found.

Comment: @Abdio68 I thought the question was for `MySQL` , check the updated answer for SQL Server

Comment: @ErgestBasha Yeah my bad, it was SQL server. I think you misunderstood my result. What I want is that for every Postalcode in Table A it needs to show the first result OF THAT postalcode in Table B.

If table A has 1111. 2222. 3333 then the result should be the first Postalcode from Table B which starts with those postalcodes --> so 1111AA, 2222AA or 3333AA. These answers could also be 1111AB etc. if the first result from table B doesnt have AA. So I want the logic to be more generic.

Comment: @Abdio68 check the updated answer, it is  dynamically

Answer (score 0):

i have change the sample from @Ergest Basha with a virtual column and index

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
Postalcode INT ,
KEY idx_sPortalcode (Postalcode)
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES 
(1111),
(2222),
(3333),
(4444);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
id INT,
Postalcode  VARCHAR(25),
sPostalcode INT  AS ( 0 + Postalcode) STORED,
KEY idx_sPortalcode (sPostalcode)
);


INSERT INTO table_b (id,Postalcode) VALUES 
(1,'1111AA'),
(2,'1111BB'),
(3,'1111CA'),
(4,'2222AA');




SELECT * FROM table_b;


-- EXPLAIN
SELECT b.Postalcode
FROM table_a  a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON b.sPostalcode=a.Postalcode
WHERE a.Postalcode=1111
ORDER BY b.id ASC LIMIT 1;
```